# Save columns in a csv files into multiple files

Tags: perl, csv, awk, paste, cut

Given a tab separated file:

```
$ cat foobar.tsv 
foo bar
blah    blah
black   sheep
```

I could do two separate cut operations to get columns into separate files:

```
$ cut -f1 foobar.tsv > foobar-c1.tsv
$ cut -f2 foobar.tsv > foobar-c2.tsv


$ cat foobar-c1.tsv 
foo
blah
black

$ cat foobar-c2.tsv 
bar
blah
sheep
```

**Is it possible to just save columns into multiple files with just one cut operation?** E.g.

```
cat foobar.tsv | cut -f1 -f2 > foobar-c1.tsv,foobar-c1.tsv
```

Note: The above command doesn't really work.

**Also Note**:

This don't count, -_-||| :

```
$ cut -f1 foobar.tsv > foobar-c1.tsv &&  cut -f2 foobar.tsv > foobar-c2.tsv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by using awk -

```
$ awk '{print $1 > "foobar-c1.csv"; print $2 > "foobar-c2.csv"}' foobar.csv 
$ cat foobar-c1.csv
foo
blah
black
$ cat foobar-c2.csv
bar
blah
sheep
```